# how to make this regular expression greedy

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

This regular expression (the extra \ for each \ is because it is in java code

```
\\*\\{[\\w\\W]*\\}\\*
```

The actual would be

```
\*\{[\w\W]*\}\*
```

but this expression is not greedy on the }* side.  I am trying to match everything between the *{ and the }* so if I have

```
*{ some comment }* hi there and some stuff *{ comment 2 }* and soe more stuff
```

should end up with

```
hi there and some stuff and soe more stuff
```

but instead it is not greedy enough.  There is info on greedy here and I thought I want X1 where that would be

```
\\*\\{[\\w\\W]*\\}1\\* or \\*\\{[\\w\\W]*\\}{1}\\*
```

but that doesn't work.  How to use their X{n} thing to force greedy here in this example?

Comment: hmmm, I think the \w\W is screwing it up since that would also match the }* but I really want to math * or } in the middle up until the next }* ...still not sure how to do this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ReplaceAll with your regex but add `?` so the [\w\W] will not greedy, like this:

```
String yourString = "*{ some comment }* hi there and some stuff *{ comment 2 }* and soe more stuff";
yourString.replaceAll("\\*\\{[\\w\\W]*?\\}\\*","");
```

then you will get that `hi there and some stuff and soe more stuff`

Comment: that worked great!!!!.....how come the ? is after the \\w\\W and before the }.  Is it that ? really switch the thing after it to greedy?  I had put a ? after the } which didn't work and you put it before...(this worked great and now I am just trying to understand why)

Comment: that `?` is not greedy approach. instead the `*` is greedy. `*?` means lazy approach zero or more occurency.

Comment: oh, yes, I see the X*? on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html as a "reluctant qualifier".  This means take as little matches as possible to match the next sequence then???  If so, I think I understand then.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
\*\{((?!\}\*).)*\}\*
```

Or in Java form:

```
\\*\\{((?!\\}\\*).)*\\}\\*
```

It uses a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to distinguish the `}*` closing tag from `}` alone. That's the `((?!\}\*).)*` part.

**Edit:** Here's a (Java) version that allows newlines. You can also use [Pattern.DOTALL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html) to make `.` include newlines, so the above patterns will work.

```
\\*\\{((?!\\}\\*)[\\s\\S])*\\}\\*
```

Note that this will not be recursive. You can't have something like `*{ foo *{ bar }* }*` and have the whole thing treated as a comment. That would make this a context-free grammar, and [trying to parse CFGs is among the most famous no-nos with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/399649).

Comment: I suppose you might be able to pull something sneaky with recursive regex (assuming java supports it), but agreed.  This was roughly what I was going to be suggesting.

Comment: hmmm, didn't work...I do have newlines in the actual code....is this going to work with newlines?  (My first version had this issue in java which is why I didn't have .*

Comment: @zebediah49 - Yup, recursive regex would probably work. I didn't mention that because I'm not sure either whether Java supports them, and because I'd still consider that a no-no here based on the level of pain and effort.

Comment: the other answer seems to work because I think it accounts for newlines

Comment: @DeanHiller - Did you see the edited version? It allows newlines. You can also use `Pattern.DOTALL` for that.